Is this a bad practice when using streams in Java?
Let’s say I have a String array, and I want to filter the array, reverse the order of the stream, and then combine the stream into one string.
Is it bad practice to include this to reverse the output order of the stream?:
**.sorted(Comparator.comparing(n -> counter[0]++)) **

(using an external int[] called counter I am able to reverse the array in the stream without having to quit the stream first).
So for example the code might look like:
String[] strs = {“Sally”, “Sold”, “Seashells”, “By”, “The”, “Seashore”};

int[] counter = {0};

return Arrays.stream(strs).filter(n -> n.charAt(0)==“S”).sorted(Comparator.comparing(n -> counter[0]++)).collect(Collectors.joining(“ “));

So what the code would return is “Seashore Seashells Sold Sally”. I know that this method of reversing a streams order works as I’ve used it many many times without error on fun practice problem in places like leetcode and codewars.
How bad of a practice is this?
I expect it to be bad practice but it makes my life so easy sometimes. I feel like I have to type and think a lot less.

reversing is usually O(N), but sorting is O(NlogN) or even O(N^2), so you're loosing performance, also depending on sorting algorithm - because of side effect of comparison you might broke A>B and B>C then A>C requirement

Yes, I'd consider that to be badly implemented. You can achieve the same with Stream.iterate(0, i -> i < strs.length, i -> i + 1).map(i -> strs[i])... Doesn't require the sort, and doesn't require the counter.

not sure about bad practice, but functional programming does not like side effects. Worse, the reason for that code is hard to understand and probably implementation dependent.

This code doesn’t even compile.

This comparator is basically the equivalent to (a,b) -> -1. It happens to work with sorting algorithms checking for a single run of presorted elements first. Since nothing in the specification guarantees this, the results must be considered just coincidence. The comparator violates the contract, e.g. signum(compare(x, y)) == -signum(compare(y, x)) is not fulfilled. Further, it does not return zero when the arguments are equal (not even when it is the same object). And so on.

@Michael you forgot the actual reversal, e.g. Stream.iterate(strs.length - 1, i -> i >= 0, i -> i - 1).map(i -> strs[i]) but besides that, you’re right. Starting with Java 21, you can also use Arrays.asList(strs).reversed().stream()

Using side effects inside a stream is usually considered bad practice, but your code is breaking the contract for comparators and only happens to work in this case by sheer luck.
The following uses a reversed view of the original array and filters it, producing the required result in O(N) time:
    String[] strs = {"Sally", "Sold", "Seashells", "By", "The", "Seashore"};
    return Arrays.asList(strs)
            .reversed().stream()
            .filter(n -> n.charAt(0)=='S')
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

